# GDB throws "Illegal Instruction" when linking -lcurl

Tags: gdb, signals

The program compiles and executes perfectly, it's just GDB Debugger which break right at the start of the execution, emerging the following dialog:

[image]

I can just press Continue and the program will run properly, but it's so annoying to have to do this in every execution.

I am Cross-Compiling remotely to Linux-ARM with [this MVS extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/) and it only happens when I link -lcurl

I have tried to disable every checkbox below "Break When Thrown" in Exception Settings, I though that at least I wouldn't be bothered anymore, but it still emerging the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that it wasn't MVS, it was remote GBD on linux instead, since I tried to debug my program from CLI and I got the same issue:

```
root@server:/.../Debug# gdb --exec=myapp
GNU gdb (Raspbian 7.7.1+dfsg-5+rpi1) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) run
Starting program: /.../Debug/myapp
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
Cannot access memory at address 0x0

Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x76a5fde8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Hello World

[Inferior 1 (process 5879) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

After that, I quickly found a workaround to make gdb ignore this signal so it wouldn't bothered me anymore stopping the proccess:

I just added `handle SIGILL nostop` to `/etc/gdb/gdbinit`